# How can i access/invoke javascript function in JSX file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a html file, .js file and .jsx file. I have added/imported both .js and .jsx files in html file.

.js file has a function to return a div tag.

I would like to render the value returned by this function to root div tag in html.

I am thinking of invoking JS function within JSX and render the value returned by this JS function using ReactDOM.render.

Is it possible to invoke a JS function from .jsx file?

index.html has below content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>`enter code here`
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/babel" src="test.jsx"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.js has below content**

```
function alertme() {
    return "<div><h1>Hello, world!</h1></div>"         
}
```

**test.jsx has below content**

```
function tick() {
  const element = (
  <div>{alertme()}</div>
  );
  ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}
tick();
```

Instead of displaying hello world it is displaying complete html tag

What could be done fix this?

Comment: You need to look into using a module loader. think `webpack`. You can't just include all your files into a page and hope to have much success. (although it is possible if you store your function to `window`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access the function of .js file in the .jsx file.

You just have to import the .js file the file where you want to use the method.

**For example:**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
```

And now in your jsx file you can use the `connect` method with required parameters.

*Above import is just for example.*

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have modified the original post to simplify my question. Can you please look at the question again now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` function provided by react to turn a string in to an React element.https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

> In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

```js
function alertme() {
  return "<div><h1>Hello, world!</h1></div>"
}

function tick() {
  const element = <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: alertme()}}></div>;
  ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}
tick();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have modified the original post to simplify my question. Can you please look at the question again now?